# Scroll to next div using arrow keys

Tags: jquery

I want my Left/Right arrow to go to the Next/Previous `.embedded_post` div. The problem is that it only works once and I can only scroll between the first and second div. I thought it was the offset of -100 but removing the offset did not do the trick. I'm thinking that after I animate to the next div, the jQuery selector has not moved anywhere so I'm stuck.

```
jQuery(document).keydown(function(e){
    switch(e.which) {
        case 37: // left
            jQuery('html, body').animate({scrollTop:jQuery('.embedded_post').prev().offset().top - 100}, 500);          
            return;
        break;

        case 38: // up
        break;

        case 39: // right
            var next_embed = jQuery('.embedded_post').next();
            jQuery('html, body').animate({scrollTop:next_embed.offset().top - 100}, 500);
            return;
        break;

        case 40: //down
        break;

        default: return; // exit this handler for other keys
    }
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.offset()` will just return the position of the first element of the list if the selector returns multiple elements.  Try adding/removing a `.current` class to the element you're currently focused on and get the next/prev of that:

```
jQuery('.embedded_post:eq(0)').addClass('current');

jQuery(document).keydown(function(e){
    switch(e.which) {
        case 37: // left
            var $current = jQuery('.embedded_post.current'),
                $prev_embed = $current.prev();
            jQuery('html, body').animate({scrollTop:$prev_embed.offset().top - 100}, 500);
            $current.removeClass('current');
            $prev_embed.addClass('current');
            return;
        break;

        case 38: // up
        break;

        case 39: // right
            var $current = jQuery('.embedded_post.current'),
                $next_embed = $current.next();
            jQuery('html, body').animate({scrollTop:$next_embed.offset().top - 100}, 500);
            $current.removeClass('current');
            $next_embed.addClass('current');
            return;
        break;

        case 40: //down
        break;

        default: return; // exit this handler for other keys
    }
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: $current.next() is not defined since I haven't given a class of 'current'. If I search for the next .embedded_post I get null again. Do I have to assign .embedded_post:eq(1) as 'next_embed' on page load?

Comment: @AlxVallejo look at the very first line of the code I posted, it adds the `.current` class to the first `.embedded_post`

Comment: Ah! I got it. I had to define $next_embed = $current.next('.embedded_post'). By the way, The '$' in front of the variable isn't necessary.

Comment: @AlxVallejo the `$` in front of the variable is a convention to help readability to indicate that the contents are a jQuery object.

Comment: hm, just wondering how I could allow default on the up and down, since I don't assign anything to it.